# invoking powershell via powercli not giving expected result

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am changing a mass of adapter from e1000 to vmxnet3

I am basically trying to filter between the vmnext adapter and the e1000 adapter with

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -match "Vmxnet"}
```

This works when i run it directly within vm

```
PS C:\Users-adm-mxj45375> get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -match "Vmxnet*"}
```

> ServiceName : vmxnet3ndis6 MACAddress : 00:50:56:88:7E:07 AdapterType
> : Ethernet 802.3 DeviceID : 1 Name : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
> NetworkAddresses : Speed : 10000000000

but when i call it via

```
$Network = Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMName -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "(get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -match 'Vmxnet'})"
```

I get

> .ServiceName : The term '.ServiceName' is not recognized as the name
> of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

I was expecting the output to be the variable $network

```
Import-Module NetAdapter
Connect-VIServer in1graapp022
$vms = Import-CSV "C:\Scripts\servers.csv"
$GC = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Please enter credentials", "Enter Guest credentials for VM", "", "")

foreach ($vm in $vms){
$VMName = $vm.Name
  $IP = $vm.IP
$SNM = $vm.SubnetMask
$GW = $vm.Gateway
$DNS1 = $vm.DNS1
$DNS2 = $vm.DNS2 
$Network = Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMName -ScriptType Powershell -ScriptText "(get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -match 'Vmxnet*'}).netconnectionid" 
$NetworkName = get-networkadapter $VMName | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "vmxnet3"} | Select-Object MacAddress
#Write-Host "Setting IP address for $VMname..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
#Sleep -Seconds 60
$netadapter = Get-NetAdapter | where MacAddress -ne "$NetworkName"}
$netadapter1 | New-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -IPAddress $IP -PrefixLength 24 -Type Unicast -DefaultGateway $GW
$netadapter2 | Set-DnsClientServerAddress  -ServerAddresses $DNS1
#$netsh = "c:\windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ip set address ""$NetworkName"" static $IP $SNM $GW"
#$netsh2 = "c:\windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ip set dnsservers ""$NetworkName"" static $DNS1"
#$netsh3 = "c:\windows\system32\netsh.exe interface ip add dnsservers ""$NetworkName"" $DNS2"
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -GuestCredential $GC -ScriptType bat -ScriptText $netadapter1
Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -GuestCredential $GC -ScriptType bat -ScriptText $netadapter2
#Invoke-VMScript -VM $VMname -GuestCredential $GC -ScriptType bat -ScriptText $netsh3
Write-Host "Setting IP address completed." -ForegroundColor Green
Sleep -Seconds 20
([WMIClass]"\\$vmname\ROOT\CImv2:Win32_Process").Create("cmd.exe /c ipconfig /registerdns")
}
```

Comment: Try using single-quotes: `-ScriptText '(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.ServiceName -match "Vmxnet"})'`

Comment: this is why i hate scripting but love guys like you

Comment: Thanks, BTW. In your code you have `$_.ServiceName -match "Vmxnet*"}`. `-match` uses regex so the asteriks here means _zero or more occurrences of the character just in front of the asteriks_. Remove the `*` there or change it into `.*`

Comment: So Following on from that i am now at the stage of setting ip addresses,
So to identify the adapter i use 
$adapter = get-netadapter -InterfaceDescription Vm* | Select-Object ifindex
This gives me

Comment: ifIndex
-------
      4   in the variable, i thought i cld then use New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $adapter to set ip however i get New-NetIPAddress : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InterfaceIndex'. Cannot convert the "@{ifIndex=4}" value of type 
"Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance" to type "System.UInt32".

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty ifindex` to get just the value. Without -ExpandProperty you create an **object** with one property, where you only need the value of that